# change srcset attribute value in picture tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<picture class="pic_test">
  <source media="(min-width:450px)" srcset="1190.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width:900px)" srcset="120.jpg">
  <img src="new.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
</picture>
```

I want to check the source media attribute is 450px or not and based on the result, i have to change the srscet attribute.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Go ahead with the _change_, What's stopping you?

Comment: we can't add any class/id for the source rit. so, how can we check the condition and change that particular source tag

Answer (score 3):

You mean

```
var $pic = $("picture"), $source=$pic.find("source"), media=$source.attr("media");
if (media.indexOf("450px")!=-1) $source.attr("srcset","small.jpg");
```

If you need specific source:

```
$("picture").find("source").each(function() {
  if ($(this).attr("media").indexOf("450px")!=-1) {
    $(this).attr("srcset","small.jpg");
  }
});
```

OR directly using the attr:

```
$('[media="(min-width:450px)"]').attr("srcset","small.jpg");
```

You may have to escape some of the - or :

Comment: thanks mplungjan for the response..its working..but it is updating all the srcset

Answer (score 0):

You can use an javascript [Image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) and get its width :

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = $("source#id??").attr("srcset");
image.onload = function() {
    var width = image.width;
    if(width == 450){
        //do stuff
    } else {
       //do other stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: `$("source#id??")` could be `$("source:eq(0)")` or `$("source:eq(1)")` ...

Comment: You should assign the event handler BEFORE setting the src

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a **[jQuery attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)** selector and change the srcset attribute like so:

```
$('[media^="(min-width:450px)"]').attr('srcset' , 'newSrcSet.jpg')
```

This would serve you better then something like `$("source:eq(0)")`, just incase the order of your source attribute changes.